# CoffeeScript, Why do I need the explicit return on a conditional

Tags: coffeescript

I was trying to learn CoffeeScript, and made this simple class as first try:

```
class test    
  fib: (x) -> 
     x if x == 0 || x == 1   
     (this.fib x-1) + (this.fib x-2)

t = new test
alert(t.fib(6));
```

This code doesn't work because it gets compiled without a return statement in the if statement. This works:

```
fib: (x) -> 
  return x if x == 0 || x == 1   
  (this.fib x-1) + (this.fib x-2)
```

Why do I need the explicit return ? Based on the language description, especially http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#expressions, I expected the `x` expression to be converted to a return by the compiler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why would you expect the `x` expression to be converted to a return?  Only the *last* expression in a method or function is converted to a return.

In Jeremy's `if/then/else` example, there are two possible last expressions, and the coffeescript parser understands to be the case in an `if/then/else`, which is not what you have here: instead, you have on expression with no lvalue, followed by another perfectly valid expression.  (There's some discussion as to whether or not the `if` statement itself is an expression; arguably, it should be read as one, but the compiled output of an `if/then/else` contains a `return` keyword in both the `then` clause and the `else` clause.)

The compiler *can't read your mind.*  It doesn't know what your intent is there with that rvalue `x` expression.  All it knows is that another perfectly valid expression in the same scope follows it.

To get the effect you want:

```
if x == 0 or x == 1
    x
else 
    (@fib x-1) + (@fib x-2)
```

Or one-liner:

```
if x == 0 or x == 1 then x else (@fib x-1) + (@fib x-2)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because CoffeeScript doesn't know, for sure, that the `x if x == 0 || x == 1` line is a return statement.

What you want is

```
class test
  fib: (x) ->
    if x == 0 || x == 1
      x
    else
      @fib(x-1) + @fib(x-2)
```

Which compiles into

```
(function() {
  var test;
  test = (function() {
    function test() {}
    test.prototype.fib = function(x) {
      if (x === 0 || x === 1) {
        return x;
      } else {
        return this.fib(x - 1) + this.fib(x - 2);
      }
    };
    return test;
  })();
}).call(this);
```

Without the `else`, the conditional isn't the last block of the function, so doesn't get the return treatment.